# apt-get behind proxy on VirtualBox Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

how can I set apt-get to work behind proxy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
http_proxy="http://host:port" apt-get something
```

should work.

If you require authentication, try

```
http_proxy="http://user:pass@host:port" apt-get something
```

And if you want this to be permenant, you should probably set the http_proxy (and ftp_proxy?) variables in your `~/.bashrc` so that all of your proxy-capable applications will work in the future, e.g. 'wget'.

Comment: one more thing to note is that if the password contains '@' then replace it with '%40' (without quotes),else it will not work

Answer (score 8):

in /etc/apt/apt.conf, add the line:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://MYDOMAIN\MYNAME:MYPASS@MY.PROXY.COM:MYPORT"
```

From: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=96802

(Note: completely stolen from [**this answer**](https://serverfault.com/questions/175495/apt-get-through-ntlm-authenticated-proxy/176821#176821) to my similar question on SF.  Cred to [**Grizzly**](https://superuser.com/users/28749/grizly))

Comment: The line needs to end with a `;`

Comment: My filename was different but this is what worked for me `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy`

Answer (score 4):

A proxy is specified by setting the `http_proxy`, `ftp_proxy` and `all_proxy` environment variables, either locally (e.g. in `~/.bashrc`) or globally (e.g. in `/etc/bash.bashrc`). These settings are honored by virtually all net-software packages (like apt-get, wget, curl etc.):

```
# HTTP proxy without authentification
export http_proxy="http://host:port"
# HTTP proxy with authentification
export http_proxy="http://user:pass@host:port"
```

However, setting them this way does not help when running `sudo apt-get ...` - and that is due to this line in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

This line *resets* all environment variables when using `sudo`, for security reasons. In order to *keep* the values of `http_proxy` etc. in a `sudo` invocation, you can specify exceptions to `env_reset` via `env_keep`:

```
# Exception specific to the command apt-get
Defaults!/usr/bin/apt-get env_keep="http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
# Exception specific to the user joe
Defaults:joe env_keep="http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

This way, you get `apt-get` to honor the *global* setting for http_proxy, instead of duplicating the setting for `apt-get` in some arcane apt-specific config file.

Comment: This is the real answer in my opinion, because you will all the time use `sudo apt-get ...` for anything. So without this entry in `/etc/sudoers`, it will not work.

Comment: This `env_reset` line is `/etc/sudoers` is really important!

Comment: @Ari: Yes it is; that is why I showed how to disable it *specifically* for `apt-get` and *specifically* for the variables necessary, instead of saying "just remove the line".

Comment: @DevSolar: yes, and plus 1 for that!